Contract like test without requests/rpc
I work on a (python) project that both depends and is depended on by other projects all developed in house.
Pkg A --> Pkg B --> Pkg C
Currently the API usage of Pkg B in Pkg A is only checked in the Pkg A tests, and not when we release a new version of Pkg B.
To make the release process more reliable I would like to implement some "Consumer Driven Contract Testing-like" tests that can verify that any externally used function/API call still works as part of the Pkg B test suit.
Is there a readily available tool, like for example Pact, that I could use for this testing that does not require the use of HTTP/REST/RPC requests? Ideally it could also verify non json objects.
Example usage of Pkg B in Pkg A
import pkg_b.some_module

cool_object: some_module.CoolClass = some_module.CoolClass()
result = cool_object.some_function(12)

